# reconfiguring pgfpages to output one page

Tags: pgfpages

I use pgfpages to produce 4up slides with beamer. I have a general setup file containing the following code:

```
% If we are in handout mode, do 4up.
\mode<handout>{
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper, border shrink=5mm, landscape]

\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},
% resized height=.65\pgfphysicalheight,
% resized width=.65\pgfphysicalwidth, 
  center = \pgfpoint{.275\pgfphysicalwidth}{.74\pgfphysicalheight}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},
% resized height=.65\pgfphysicalheight,
% resized width=.65\pgfphysicalwidth,
  center = \pgfpoint{.725\pgfphysicalwidth}{.74\pgfphysicalheight}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},
% resized height=.65\pgfphysicalheight,
% resized width=.65\pgfphysicalwidth,
  center = \pgfpoint{.275\pgfphysicalwidth}{.26\pgfphysicalheight}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},
% resized height=.65\pgfphysicalheight,
% resized width=.65\pgfphysicalwidth,
 center = \pgfpoint{.725\pgfphysicalwidth}{.26\pgfphysicalheight}
}
}
```

Now students asked me to provide a 1up version of the slides because of readability. I want to tell pgfpages to print one slide per page despite the earlier configuration. Is this possible?

I already tried: `\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm, landscape]`